# How to display LONGBLOB field data in TWIG file

Tags: symfony, twig

I am working in Symfony2. I have a field in table that uses `LONGBLOB`. So now I want to display field data.When I display this LONGBLOB field data it show's me text like this
**`Resource id #404`** but actually in field I have stored the dummy text.

This is my defaultcontrolle file code

**DefaultController.php**

```
function video_showAction($id)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();       
    $video = $em->getRepository('MyBundle:Video')->find($id);

    return $this->render('MyBundle:Default:VideoShow.html.twig', array('qShow' => $video ));
}
```

**VideoShow.html.twig**

```
Description: {{ qShow.description }}
// it will display  "Resource id #404"
```

How can I display the actual data not he Refrence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the Solution.
I just need to use `stream_get_contents`. So I have put this into Getter method of my Entity.
Like this

**MyEntity.php**

```
// Getter Function need to be change like this
public function getDescription()
{
    if ($this->description != '')
        return stream_get_contents($this->description);
    return $this->description;
}
```

Now When I display the content it shows me the Actual Data that the Recourse Id contains.

Answer (score 2):

As you mentioned in your own answer, you should rewrite your getter function.

I propose something like that:

```
private $descriptionAsText = null;

public function getDescription()
{
    if (is_null($this->descriptionAsText))
    {
       $this->descriptionAsText = stream_get_contents($this->description);
    }
    return $this->descriptionAsText;
}
```

If your stream can change in the same instance of the entity, you can eventually use:

```
public function getDescription()
{
    rewind($this->description);
    return stream_get_contents($this->description);
}
```

I dislike your current method, as if you need to use `{{ qShow.description }}` twice or more, you will get troubles because of your **stream offset**.

You need to [rewind](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rewind.php) your resource each time you're doing a `stream_get_contents`, because it places the offset at the end of your stream (or at the specified length).

You can reproduce this behavior using the following code:

```
<?php

file_put_contents("/tmp/test.txt", "Hello, world!");

$handle = fopen("/tmp/test.txt", "r");
$contents = stream_get_contents($handle);
echo "Contents A = {$contents}\n"; // Contents A = Hello, world!

$contents = stream_get_contents($handle);
echo "Contents B = {$contents}\n"; // Contents B =

fclose($handle);
```

This behaviour is there since PHP 5.3 (I guess), so if you try this code on Codepad (who uses 5.2.5), you will not reproduce.

Answer (score 0):

For using LONGBLOB firs you need do the following works. this works are describe in detail at the following link please check that you do all of them and then try again to show your qShow.description on your twig file. I think "Resource id #404" error say you that you have problem reading your resource with 404 ID Number.

http://symfony2.ylly.fr/add-new-data-type-in-doctrine-2-in-symfony-2-jordscream/

Comment: No it's not an error.It basically store the Content Resource.